# Unable to use Swift protocol in Objective C class, as it causes Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm not able to find a solution anywhere to this :

My app has Swift protocols and I need to implement that in an old Objective-C class. After implementing the protocol when I create the object of Objective C class, Xcode shows segmentation fault error 11. Dig into many posts to find the solution but no success.

To illustrate the problem I have created a demo iOS project here :

https://github.com/tusharbhatta/SwiftSegmentationFault

> ## UPDATE:
>
> Made a work around to the problem. Check it out on branch 'solved' in
>   the above same repo. :)

But still please help if you know any better solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: `segmentation fault error 11` Please send the crash report to Apple.

Comment: I downloaded your project and tried to build it - what I noticed is that when I remove HatchbackCar from the bridging header, the project compiles. Of course then I cannot use it in Swift code. Maybe the problem is with both using the Swift code in Obj-c and vice-versa. Anyway looks like a bug in Xcode to me.

Comment: @Eric Aya, yes I made a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @Tushar I have solved the issue :) There are few bugs I am just typing the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Apple engineers about my bug report at Apple Developer Bug Reporting portal that the issue has been fixed in the Beta Xcode 8.3 and the project successfully builds. Here is the actual reply from Apple :

> Engineering has the following feedback for you:
>
> The project builds successfully with Xcode 8.3 beta 2.
>
> Please verify this issue with the Xcode 8.3 beta and update your bug
>   report at https://bugreport.apple.com/ with your results.
>
> Xcode 8.3 beta 2 (8W120l) https://developer.apple.com/download/ Posted
>   Date: Feb 6th, 2017
>
> Thank you.
>
> Thank you for your assistance in helping us discover and isolate bugs
>   within our products.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Apple Developer Support Worldwide Developer Relations

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues with your code follow the steps. Hope this will resolve your issue.

1). Go to Build Settings and search for the "Defines Module" change its value to YES.

2). Go to  'HatchbackCar.h' now remove '@protocol CarProtocol;' and "CarProtocol" from it.

3). Now clear project.

4). Go to 'HatchbackCar.m' add following code.

```
 @interface HatchbackCar() <CarProtocol>

@end
```

5). Now clear project once again.

6). Build project.

Comment: But that way it won't be easy to use the object of HatchbackCar in a swift array of type CarProtocol, because the compiler is not able to see private implementation. For example :
var cars = [CarProtocol]()
        
        let hyundaiSantro = HatchbackCar("Huyndai Santro", wheels: 4)
        cars.append(hyundaiSantro)

Comment: i have tried to solve error in code as you asked. further not tested the code.

Comment: I really appriciate your solution for the work around in Xcode 8.2.  Thanks a lot man :)